# Why and I getting this ansible-playbook error: ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm using the win_shell:  module in ansible 2.9 to run powershell script and when I format the code with trailing \ then I get jinja2 block or quotes error

```
- name: Copy Java Files to E:\Oracle directory structure
  win_shell: |
    $src = 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\';
```

results in in jinja2 block or quotes error whereas

```
- name: Copy Java Files to E:\Oracle directory structure
  win_shell: |
    $src = 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161';
```

if I wanted to have the backslash at the end of the statement what should I do?

Comment: You can try using double backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible in general doesn't really like special characters in the tasks name. I would remote the `E:\` from the tasks name.

Comment: I'll take that into consideration.  the error is if I have the \ at the end of the $src path variable

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a variable to skip the backslash issue:

```
---
 - hosts: all
   vars:
    string_to_update: "\\"

   tasks:
    - name: Copy Java Files to E:\Oracle directory structure
      win_shell: |
        $src = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\{{string_to_update}}";
```